# capturing EOF sent from netcat

Tags: c, multithreading, eof, file-descriptor, netcat

I am implementing a multi threaded chat server just to learn. I am connecting clients through netcat. I need to broadcast the message received by a client to other connected clients. That part is already done. What I am stuck in is, I need to find whether the client sent an EOF, and then remove that specific client from my data structures and free the resources.how do i capture the EOF sent from the client?

Plus EOF means ctrl+D right?

I have written the following code segment to do that. But it doesn't work. where have I gone wrong. without the if segment everything works fine except removing a client.with the if segment nothing seems to be working.

```
char buffer[MAXMSG];

    while (!quit)
    {


        read(connfd,buffer,MAXMSG);//read a message from this client
        if(bufffer==EOF){
            break;
        }
        broadcast_msg(buffer);
    //if EOF quit, otherwise broadcast it using broadcast_msg()
    }
    perror("Client disconnected");
    close(clients[(int)arg]->sd);
    free(clients[(int)arg]);
    checkemptyarray[(int)arg]=0;


return NULL;
```

Comment: More like Ctrl+D means EOF (in the context of passing it to a running application) :)

Comment: what is your operating system? for windows it is ctrl+z, for linux it is ctrl+D

Answer (score 0):

You need to examine the return value of `read()`. `read()` will return the number of bytes received on success, or 0 if the sender has no more data to send, or -1 if an error occurred.

```
ssize_t result = read(connfd,buffer,MAXMSG);
if (result <= 0) {
    if (result < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fd: %d, ", connfd);
        perror("read");
    }
    break;
}
```

It looks like you expect the `buffer` to be a NUL terminated string. You need to do that explicitly in your code, since `read()` won't do it for you, unless the client included it as part of the data it sent:

```
buffer[result] = '\0';
broadcast_msg(buffer);
```

Comment: so does the EOF make result equal to less than zero?

Comment: @DesirePRG: There is no EOF *per se*. The client indicates it has no more data to send, either by closing the connection, or by issuing a `shutdown()` with `SHUT_WR`. This results in a `0` return value from `read()`.

Comment: Thanx. :) I will work through the code with the information you provided